# F# Dictionary of Lists Equivalent

Tags: f#, monogame, f#-3.0, c#-to-f#

I've just started learning F# and I'm using it with Monogame to create a simple game to help myself learn the various features of the language. I've got my window up and running and have basic drawing working (I'm able to draw a single object to the screen).

My current goal is to draw a scene using different 2D textures on n layers. For example, layer 1 could have the players, layer 2 could have the scene items, such as trees and rocks and layer 3 could have the mountains in the background. Layer n could have n items. Order matters at the scene level but (at the moment) does not matter at the layer level.

In C#, I would do something like the below, using a Dictionary of Lists, with the dictionary key being the layer and the list being the items that get drawn on that layer. However, after a bit of searching, I have been unable to find the equivalent "functional" way of doing it. Of course, it's easy for me to pull in and use the .NET collections, but I'd like learn the functional way before I jump to that.

Note, the code sample below is pseudocode and won't compile (for example, Texture2D's don't have an X or Y component). It's just to illustrate general code flow.

```cs
public class Game
{
    var items = new Dictionary<int, List<Texture2D>>();

    public void Initialize()
    {
        items.Add(1, new List<Texture2D>());
        items.Add(2, new List<Texture2D>());
        items.Add(3, new List<Texture2D>());

        items[1].Add(playerOneTexture);
        items[3].Add(jaggedMountainsTexture);
        items[2].Add(rocksTexture);
        items[3].Add(rollingHillsTexture);
        items[1].Add(playerTwoTexture);
        items[2].Add(treeTexture);
    }

    public void Update
    {
        //Example of update (in this case, just move stuff to the right)
        foreach(var key in items.Keys)
        {
            foreach(var texture in items[key])
            {
                texture.X++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Draw
    {
        var layers = items.Keys.ToList.Sort(); //Or other appropriate sort function
        foreach(var layer in layers)
        {
            foreach(var texture in items[layer])
            {
                DrawToScreen(texture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Q: What is the functional way of solving this problem in F#?**

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way would be to use F# `dicts` and `lists`.

Some simple examples:

```
let items = dict [1,[playerOneTexture;...]...]

let update = items.Values 
|> Seq.iter (fun t -> t |> Seq.iter (fun q -> do something here
```

etc.

F# `dict` and `list` function similar to their C# equivalent, except they are immutable

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am unable to find any documentation for dict. Since I'll need to load the textures at runtime, I can't hardcode the dictionary initialization. Could you please show me how to populate the dictionary at runtime?

Comment: @user3481784 - the `dict` function will take any sequence type where the lements are tuples and convert it to a dictionary.  documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx

Comment: How do I create a sequence of tuples at runtime? I've looked at the MSDN documentation for sequences, but it seems to describe building lists at using functions when a particular index is looked up, rather then populating the list with values ahead of time.

Comment: Here's a sequence of integer tuples created at runtime: `seq { for i in 0..5 -> i, i * 5 }`. Lists are also sequences, because `seq<t>` is simply an alias for `IEnumerable<T>`.